Error loading .jpg images in tkinter window using tk.PhotoImage
Question:
I am working on a tkinter application where I need to display images in the GUI. While loading .png images works perfectly fine, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to load .jpg images using tk.PhotoImage.
Here is the snippet of code I am using:
`...
# Function for the additional button click action
def additional_function():
    try:
        image_path = "output/exp/img.jpg"
        image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
        img_label.config(image=image)
        img_label.image = image  # to keep a reference
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading image: {e}")

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Show The Result", command=additional_function, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)
button2.config(font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"), fg="white")
button2.place(relx=(start_x + end_x) / 2 / root.winfo_screenwidth(), rely=(sum(row_heights[:y]) + row_heights[y] + 600) / root.winfo_screenheight(), anchor=tk.CENTER)`
...`

However, when attempting to load a .jpg image, I encounter the following error:
Error loading image: couldn't recognize data in image file "output/exp/img.JPG"
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this problem. Thank you in advance.

I had the idea to use Python library 'PILL' and it worked well with .jpg but I want to use the tk.PhotoImage.

You can't load .jpg images unfortunately.
From the docs:

tkinter.PhotoImage(name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw)
Widget which can display images in PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG format.

As a work-around I would suggest to convert the image to one of the image formats above.
You could convert an image easily here or could convert an image on the fly in python.
PIL and Image are nice libraries for this purpose:
import Image
img = Image.open("file.jpg")
img.save("file.png", "PNG")

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("file.jpg")
img.save("file.png")

If you dislike creating these files next to your source files, you can use tempfile to create temporary, hidden files.
Alternative:
If you are fine with not using tkinter.PhotoImage, you could also directly use PIL to load the image:
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
img = Image.open(image_path)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


Yes, this is correct. After posting the question, I used a script to change the format of the image to .png and it worked well. I also used PILL library with .jpg and it worked well.
